# Remove Ads - In App Purchase

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase

In my game I want to have the In App Purchase to remove the ads. I use Admob and my code works well for the ads. The problem I have is that my code for the ads is in the GameViewController.swift. But my In-App Purchases are in my PurchaseScene.swift.

I didn´t find a way to make a remove function in my PurchaseScene.swift which works. So the code I have in my GameViewController.swift:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var banner: GADBannerView!

    var interstital: GADInterstitial!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ShowAd(_:)), name: "ShowInterAdKey", object: nil)

        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
            // Configure the view.
            let skView = self.view as! SKView
            skView.showsFPS = false
            skView.showsNodeCount = false

            /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.size = self.view.bounds.size

            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }

        self.banner.adUnitID = "myUnitID"
        self.banner.rootViewController = self

        var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()

        self.banner.loadRequest(request)

        request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

        interstital = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "myUnitID")

        let req = GADRequest()
        interstital.loadRequest(req)
    }

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(bannerView: GADBannerView!) {
        banner.hidden = false
    }

    func adView(bannerView: GADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
        banner.hidden = true
    }

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Phone {
            return .AllButUpsideDown
        } else {
            return .All
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func ShowAd(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (interstital.isReady) {
            interstital.presentFromRootViewController(self)
            interstital = CreateAd()
        }

    }

    func CreateAd() -> GADInterstitial {
        let interstital = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "myUnitID")
        interstital.loadRequest(GADRequest())
        return interstital
    }
}
```

And now I have this code in Utilities.swift.

```
import Foundation
```

class Utility {

```
// Gets a path to your app's local directory where it has permissions to write
static func getFilePathForFile(fileName:String) -> String {
    let libraryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

    return libraryPath.stringByAppendingString("/").stringByAppendingString(fileName as String)
}

static func writeValueToFile(value:String, fileName:String) {

    do {
        try value.writeToFile(Utility.getFilePathForFile(fileName), atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    } catch {
        print("\(error)")
    }
}

static func readValueFromFile(fileName:String) -> String? {

    let file = Utility.getFilePathForFile(fileName);

    if let value = try? String(contentsOfFile: file) {
        return value;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

}

And the call function is in the PurchaseScene.swift like this:

```
let file = "IAP_Ads"



func removeADS() {

    Utility.writeValueToFile("YES", fileName: file);




if let value = Utility.readValueFromFile(file) {
    print("file exists... value = %@" , Utility.readValueFromFile(file) )

    let adsRemoved = (value == "YES" ? true : false)

    if adsRemoved {
        // Code to remove ads, but i don't know what code
        print("ads removed")


    }
 }
}
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: AnyObject in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        var node = self.nodeAtPoint(location)
if removeadsBTN.containsPoint(location){
            for product in list {
                let prodID = product.productIdentifier
                if(prodID == "myProductID") {
                    p = product
                    buyProduct()
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }


}
```

STEP 3: buyProduct()

```
func buyProduct() {
    print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    let pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    Utility.writeValueToFile("YES", fileName: "IAP_Ads") //new code
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming your purchase screen is separate from your GameViewController? If so, and you have to change screens (say, like push/pop via a navigation controller), then all you need to do is check the state of the "purchase" in the GameViewController when the `viewWillAppear` function is called. If it's via an overlay, and your GameViewController's lifecycle methods won't be called, then you need to use the observer/notification model.

Comment: @thephatp Yes I have a separate purchase screen. How can I check the state of the "purchase" in the GameViewController? Do you have an code example? Thank you very much

Comment: tracking state isn't bad, but since this is a purchase, I assume you want to be able to restore the purchase at some point if the user changes devices. Just keep that in mind for later. For now, just getting to the "finding state," let me get some code for you. Are you using Core Data, or no? (That'll help me to give you the right piece of code without giving you too much work.)

Comment: @thephatp Okey that will be great. No it's a sprite kit Game. I think in this I can't use core data. Thank you! :)

Comment: so you added the Utility file, and you added the methods provided to your PurchaseScene.swift. **Step 1** is done. **Step 2**, in  PurchaseScene, the line added: `if let value = Utility.readValueFromFile(file)`, replace `print("ads removed")` with code to remove any ads that may be visible. **Step 3** in `buyProduct()` method, call `Utility.writeValueToFile("YES", "IAP_Ads")`. **Step 4**, update `GameViewController` it call `Utility.readValueFromFile("IAP_Ads")` and if ads should be removed, then **don't** show the view that presents ads.

Comment: @thephatp I edited my question. So for Step 2 i don't know what code should i use. Step 3 is done i think. And Step 4 i don't understand how I can write a code that the ads don't show. Thank you! :)

Comment: without seeing a LOT more of your code, how your handling certain things, etc, I can't tell you how to do Step 2. That said, I can tell you how to do Step 4. I'm going to update my answer below with the code, because it's too painful to describe here. That said, Step 4 really simple with what I've given you so far. I'm pretty sure you could have figured this out on your own.

Comment: I have now updated my answer below to include how to not show the ad in GameViewController after the in app purchase. Note that this does not remove them from the view, but the next time the view loads you should not see the add.

Comment: To remove the ads immediately upon purchase (rather than waiting for GameViewController to "reload") would be to either (1) override the viewWillAppear method in GameViewController and remove the banner view, or (2) find a way to know PurchaseScene has closed and remove the banner at that point. NOTE: To remove the banner, you add the same logic for checking to see if the purchase was made, and if so, call `self.banner.removeFromSuper()`.

Comment: @thephatp Now it works. :) Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: glad I could help! Don't forget to accept my answer below, please. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'm not proficient with Swift, but if you don't know Objective-C, I can try to convert this for you, it'll just take me a little more time.

Now, this may not be the ideal solution, but it should get you up and running quickly. Once you understand what's happening, you can modify the code to meet your needs. For example, you could choose to store multiple values in a single file. If you do this, you could use JSON format, or you just make a format like :  and let a line break separate the values, etc.

```
// Gets a path to your app's local directory where it has permissions to write
+ (NSString *)getFilePathForFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString *libraryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    return [libraryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}

// Writes a value to a file. Cast your value to a string before passing it in.
+ (void)writeValue:(NSString *)value toFile:(NSString *)file
{
    [value writeToFile:[self getFilePathForFile:file] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
}

// Reads a value from a file. Once you have this value, cast it back to the type you need.
+ (NSString *)readValueFromFile:(NSString *)file
{
    NSString *filePath = [self getFilePathForFile:file];

    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
        return nil;

    return [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                        error:NULL];
}
```

Copy and past these methods into a file somewhere. If you use a utility/helper file, put it there, because these can be static methods (the '+' sign), so they can live anywhere. Replace `self` in these methods with the Class in which you put them.

Next, call it like shown below.

To Write:

```
// User purchased to remove adds, so let's save that now. (IAP stands for In-App Purchase
[self writeValue:@"YES" toFile:@"IAP_RemoveAds"];
```

To Read:

```
// Loading my new view, so need to check to see if the removal of ads was purchased...
NSString * sPurchased = [self readValueFromFile:@"IAP_RemoveAds"];
BOOL removeAds = [sPurchased boolValue];
```

Hope this helps.

**Swift Code:**

Put this in a file, say call it `Utilities.swift`:

```
import Foundation

class Utility {

    // Gets a path to your app's local directory where it has permissions to write
    static func getFilePathForFile(fileName:String) -> String {
        let libraryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]

        return libraryPath.stringByAppendingString("/").stringByAppendingString(fileName as String)
    }

    static func writeValueToFile(value:String, fileName:String) {

        do {
            try value.writeToFile(Utility.getFilePathForFile(fileName), atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        } catch {
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }

    static func readValueFromFile(fileName:String) -> String? {

        let file = Utility.getFilePathForFile(fileName);

        if let value = try? String(contentsOfFile: file) {
            return value;
        }

        return nil;
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
let file = "IAP_Ads"

// Writing to the file
Utility.writeValueToFile("YES", fileName: file);


// Reading from the file
if let value = Utility.readValueFromFile(file) {
    print("file exists... value = %@" , Utility.readValueFromFile(file) )

    let adsRemoved = (value == "YES" ? true : false)

    if adsRemoved {
        print("ads removed")

        // Remove the ads here
    }
}
```

And because I can't keep describing code in commends, I'm putting a modified version of your `GameViewController` class' `viewDidLoad` method below which incorporates the logic for not including the adds whenever that view is loaded in the future:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ShowAd(_:)), name: "ShowInterAdKey", object: nil)

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        scene.size = self.view.bounds.size

        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }

    if let value = Utility.readValueFromFile(file) {

        let adsRemoved = (value == "YES" ? true : false)

        if !adsRemoved {
            // Ads have not been purchased yet, so show the ads

            self.banner.adUnitID = "myUnitID"
            self.banner.rootViewController = self

            var request: GADRequest = GADRequest()

            self.banner.loadRequest(request)

            request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

            interstital = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "myUnitID")

            let req = GADRequest()
            interstital.loadRequest(req)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I never used Objective-C  so i can`t translate this. What do you mean with "paste the methods into a file somewhere"? Shouldn`t I paste this code in the GameViewController?

Comment: @Claudio13 updated answer. Let me know if this works for you or if you have any other questions. Put the `Utility.writeValueToFile(...)` call in your `PurchaseScene.swift` file when you confirm their purchase. Put the logic for reading from the file in your GameViewController in the viewDidLoad and remove the ads.

Comment: Sorry that Im a little bit slow on the uptake, but Im a beginner. The code doesn't work at the moment but i think thats cause I put it not to the right place or made something wrong. I made a new file Utilities.swift and putted the code in there. But the second code doesn't work. Thank you very much for the help and your endurance!

Comment: @Claudio13 can you explain a little more what the "second code" is? For testing purposes, you could probably past the static methods (everything between the braces for the Utility class) in both of your files that already exist. But after testing (assuming it works), you'll want to consolidate in one place to keep it clean. Having the literal `"IAP_RemoveAds"` in multiple places, because if you change the name, you have to be sure to change it everywhere.

Comment: @Claudio13 added `let file = "IAP_Ads"` to the "Call it like this:" section in the answer.

Comment: With the second code i meaned the "Call it like this". I edited my Answer in the top. Thats what i made now but im not sure if i called the Utilities in the right way.

Comment: @Claudio13, I answered this one in comments to your original post, since that's where your code is. Made more sense to refer to it up there. Check it out and let me know.